# How can i click on the image button when i know only div id and img src in C#?

Tags: c#, html, button, click

I was searching solutions on Stack Overflow but didn't find it so that's new question. I'm making program which will login you into the web game and click to start. Here is problem. I was trying some codes like:

```
HtmlElementCollection startButton = mapWebBrowser.Document.All;
            foreach (HtmlElement start in startButton)
            {
                if (start.GetAttribute("src") == "/do_img/global/text_tf.esg?l=cs&s=16&t=header_start&f=eurostyle_tbla&color=white&bgcolor=green&h=18")
                {
                    start.InvokeMember("click");
                }
        }
```

This doesn't work.
Can you help me? Code of image button is:

```
<div id="header_start_btn" >
            <img src="/do_img/global/text_tf.esg?l=cs&s=16&t=header_start&f=eurostyle_tbla&color=white&bgcolor=green&h=18" />
        </div>
```

And this is full code of my project: [Full code](http://pastebin.com/MMdcDcMG)

Comment: Can you tell me what is bad on this question?

Comment: Nothing at all. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to consider here.  You should set the source in the Form_Load event:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mapWebBrowser.Url = new Uri("...");            
}
```

Then you need to wait for the document to render before looking, with the following code:

```
private void mapWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   HtmlElement imageTag = mapWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("header_start_btn").Children[0];
}
```

Just tested this and it works.

Comment: It's harder thank you think. Here is full code http://pastebin.com/nfcqZBYq
In the moment in Form1_Load is 1 thing. I dont know if i can give there next.